# shared login system between sylius and other part of the symfony app?

Tags: symfony, sylius

I am new to Symfony and Sylius, and I have installed Sylius which is installed as a symfony "vendor" bundle by default.
I have moved the route to Sylius (which is accessible by default at  "/") to "/shop", and I will developp myself the home page and other pages (not related to the shop, like information pages, etc.)

But, I need authentication in these other pages to manage user accounts (with data not related to the shop).

What I would like is a shared authentication system, but I don't know if it is possible to use Sylius' one and how to do this.

Thanks for you help !

Jon

Comment: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/2931

Answer (score 1):

THis is related to Symfony, you will need to override security in way to share context - your app and Sylius. Then some parts of Sylius will be locked as now.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

Answer (score 0):

What I have made is route my Bundle under "/admin/blog". As my route is under /admin, I have to authenticate with the Sylius authentication, and it Seems to work well ! :-)